# Why is my login page being shown as text in a popup rather than as formatted HTML

Tags: gwt, spring-security

I am using GWT with Spring security to manage user log in.
Why do I get a popup window with the HTML contents of my login page as text instead of being directed to my properly formatted login page when the session expires and I try to do something in my app???

I have based my implementation on [this post](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/12/securing-gwt-apps-with-spring-security.html).
My configuration looks like this:

```
    <security:http>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/styles/images/**" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/styles/*/images/**" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/styles/*/*.css" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/styles/*.css" filters="none" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
        access="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:form-login
        login-page="/login.jsp"
        default-target-url='/my-app.html' always-use-default-target="true" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/login.jsp" />
    <security:form-login authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/login.jsp"/>

</security:http>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please show your login.jsp code

Comment: The login page displays correctly before the user logs in... and after the user is logged out as well... The problem only comes up when the user is logged out by "accident" (session expires) and the user tries to perform some action in the app (which is a GWT app), so I think the login.jsp page is not relevant (it's pure JSP, nothing to do with GWT).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer my own question in the hope it may be useful to other people.

The whole problem was due to the way I was handling InvocationException, which is thrown when the user attempts to perform an action which is blocked by Spring security (due to session time-out for example).

I was showing a popup by using Window.alert("Explanation to the user, details" + e.getMessage()), where message is the message received from the Exception coming from the server. This works fine if the server actually sent an exception, but in the case where Spring attempts to re-direct the user to the login page, it seems that what is shown is the JSP page itself!!! I created my own popup (using a GWT's DialogBox) and the problem is now solved.

Lesson learned: do not use Window.alert() for anything other than debugging!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you are writting, I assume, that you have a HTML field which you use something like this:

```
final HTML html= new HTML(text);
//or    
final HTML html= new HTML();
html.add(text);
```

where the text is your formatted html (something like this `<h1>username:</h1>...`). The problem now is that you get your output is exactly the `<h1>username:</h1>...` and not as you would expect the username: formatted as h1 and so on.

This is because the HTML class automaticlly escapes you the text you put into it "SafeHTML" text. (see [Developer's Guide - SafeHtml](http://code.google.com/intl/de-AT/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml.html) )

To actaully output the formatted html, you have to create your one SafeHTML class. Here is a simple example:

```
SafeHtml safeHtml = new SafeHtml() {

            @Override
            public String asString() {
                return "<h1>Username</h1>";
            }
        };
```

However you should read the [Developer's Guide - SafeHtml](http://code.google.com/intl/de-AT/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideSecuritySafeHtml.html)!

Hope this was your problem^^

Comment: That is not a good way to build safehtml instances - it may even encourage developers to start mixing variables in there, and then we are just as bad as if SafeHtml didn't exist. Encourage the use of  SafeHtmlBuilder, and the methods for escaping text vs allowing a known good constant. Your example isn't unsafe, but it might suggest to some that it is acceptable to subclass SafeHtml on their own.

Comment: yes I know... however I still haven't found out how the SafeHtml class is intended to be used... :/

Comment: SafeHtmlBuilder is good for most things, SafeHtmlTemplates are pretty nice too. If you must, resort to SafeHtmlUtils. Generally you won't be consuming those SafeHtml instances much, but passing them to widgets (unless you yourself build widgets). Biggest use case is for Cells, so large tables of complex cells can quickly/safely be built.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help, but the problem has nothing to do with that because my login page is a pure jsp page and is not rendered by GWT. The GWT app is only loaded after the user successfully logs in. The problem is that when the session expires (and the user is therefore logged out), Spring tries to redirect the user to login.jsp but for some reason, instead of being redirected, the jsp page is shown as text in a popup.